# Example of family of integral curves with constant gonality and increasing genus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, algebraic-curves, projective-schemes

Are there examples of a family of integral curves over some field $k$ which have constant gonality but increasing genus?

**A related question:** If I give you two non-negative integers $n$ and $g$, can you provide an example of a curve with *gonality* at most $n$ and *genus* at least $g$?

Thanks for any input or references!

Comment: What do you mean by a "family of curves"? Perhaps a morphism $X\to Y$ of relative dimension $1$? For the 2nd question, we have hyperelliptic (gonality  $2$) curve of arbitrarily large genus.